# Unity make dotted line renderer

Tags: unity

I know, that this question was asked before, but I could not find a proper answer to this. So how can I make my line dotted? I added a texture with a dot, but it just gets stretched for the length of the line, which is obviously not what I want. I'm using C# btw, if some code is needed here.

Edit: Inspector:

[image]

Edit: New Code :

```
public class dashedLine : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 newPosition;
    private LineRenderer line;

    void Awake()
    {
        line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    void Update()
        {
        line.material.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", new Vector2(Time.timeSinceLevelLoad * 4f, 0f));
        line.material.SetTextureScale("_MainTex", new Vector2(newPosition.magnitude, 1f));
        line.SetPosition(0, newPosition);
       }
}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Edit: This works now, when I use a Texture which has multiple dots in a row and put it to a material with Shader: Unlit/Transparent. I still don't know, why it's not working with a single dot.

Edit2: I had to recreate the dot texture with a single dot and it worked, so there was some issue on my side. Everything works now fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a texture with a circle to a material, assign that material to a line renderer, and attach a script to it that will scale the texture relative to the magnitude of the line. Here's some code:

```
public class LineScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private LineRenderer line;

    void Awake()
    {
        line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 newPosition = (Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        line.material.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", new Vector2(Time.timeSinceLevelLoad * 4f, 0f));
        line.material.SetTextureScale("_MainTex", new Vector2(newPosition.magnitude, 1f));
        line.SetPosition(0, newPosition);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mhm I get an error, that he couldn't find my texture, my material is called Dotted_Line and the Texture, which I've put into "Albedo" is called Dot. I tried both and both didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using a different shader - Unlit/Transparent, or Sprites/Default.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the material, but I guess Standard shader doesn't have a "_MainTex" properly. So using a different shader should fix it. Or download the source and look at what the textures are called in the default shader. My guess would be "_Albedo".

Comment: Okay since I have some other setup with camera and stuff I changed the code a bit, so that I can manually set the new position stuff, but the line still just gets stretched and not dotted :/ Added my code in the question.

Comment: Okay I tried to update my question, so that I provide everything you could need to know.

Comment: Make sure the new position is set to the second point of the line. You could even get rid of the new position and simply look at what the position of the second point is from the line renderer.

Comment: I tried it, since you set position 0 in your code I changed it to 1, but that makes no difference. And I thought I need "newPosition" since you use it in the SetTextureScale Method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37462/discussion-between-thunder-and-iggy).