# Unity LineRenderer custom reapeted Texture with margin

Tags: textures, unity

I have a LineRenderer, which has 1 dot as texture, which is repeated over the whole line. Now I want to know, if there is some way to give this dots a margin, so that I can make the gap between them bigger.

[image]

For the moment there is no gap, I could make a new Texture and add the margin there, but I hope for some more dynamic way to do this.

Edit: Inspector View :
[image]

Comment: could you paste a screenshot of your inspector for this line renderer? I just get one stretched texture on a line. How do you do it?

Comment: Done, but I guess that won't help much, but here is a thread which should contain all you need : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/118814/unity-make-dotted-line-renderer/118818?noredirect=1#comment208679_118818

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you need are dots, I wouldn't even use a texture for this. We can shape a repeated circular zone to our liking within the shader:

[image: LineRenderer with custom dotted line shader]

By playing with the Repeat Count and Spacing material parameters, you can change the  number & spacing of the dots. Offset will shift the dot pattern along the line.

Here's the shader I wrote for this:

```
Shader "Unlit/DottedLineShader"
{
    Properties
    {
        _RepeatCount("Repeat Count", float) = 5
        _Spacing("Spacing", float) = 0.5
        _Offset("Offset", float) = 0
    }
        SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType" = "Transparent" "Queue" = "Transparent" }
        LOD 100

        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        ZWrite Off

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            float _RepeatCount;
            float _Spacing;
            float _Offset;

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                fixed4 color : COLOR0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;              
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                fixed4 color : COLOR0;
            };

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                o.uv.x = (o.uv.x + _Offset) * _RepeatCount * (1.0f + _Spacing);
                o.color = v.color;

                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                i.uv.x = fmod(i.uv.x, 1.0f + _Spacing);
                float r = length(i.uv - float2(1.0f + _Spacing, 1.0f) * 0.5f) * 2.0f;

                fixed4 color = i.color;
                color.a *= saturate((0.99f - r) * 100.0f);

                return color;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

One little issue: in my test scene this gets rendered behind the skybox. I'm used to "Queue"="Transparent" fixing that, so I may have something else a little off in here, but I don't have time to debug right now. If it poses a problem for you, you can make the dots alpha tested instead of blended as a quick & dirty fix.

Comment: Okay this works pretty good, but is there a possibility to set the scale? Because depending on the length of the line, the dots are getting oval, I could fix this issue for the texture with this: line.material.SetTextureScale(....). But this is not working anymore.

Comment: Instead you'd use `line.material.SetFloat("_RepeatCount", foo);` where `foo` is a float describing your desired number of dots. You can also cache the property ID from [Shader.PropertyToID](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Shader.PropertyToID.html) and use the integer version of [Material.SetFloat](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetFloat.html) if you're using it a lot.

Comment: Okay, so I can still not increase the gap between the dots right? I mean I can lower the amount of the dots but then I will get ovals. And is there an easy way to make the offset work here? Sorry I'm completely new to shaders :/

Comment: Yeah obviously, but I would like to keep the dot size and increase the gap at the same time, would that be possible? And the offset part was nice to "animate" the dots, since I was able to constantly increase the offset so the dots were flowing along the line.

Comment: @Thunder updated with requested parameters

Comment: Okay thats working great, thanks for your awesome help :)